# How many words should there be?

Tags: c#

In C# I have got a text file where it reads the first line which is exactly written as: "OriginalName" + "_Parsed.txt".

Now I have a question where it says add summary that includes the count of ALL Words.

Now the issue I have is I don't know if the answer should be 2, 3 or 4.

2 because there are two words without spaces.
3 because txt should be a word after .
4 because there are four whole words which are 'Original', 'Name', 'Parsed' and 'txt'.

My question is simply if you are faced with this question, how many words should there be?

Below is my current code where I replace the space and + symbol:

```
string textLine = "";
System.IO.StreamReader txtReader;
txtReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file_name);

textLine = textLine + txtReader.ReadLine();

while (txtReader.Peek() != -1) ;

MessageBox.Show(textLine);

char[] seperator = new char[] {' ', '+'};
int numberOfWords 
  = textLine.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
```

Comment: You should ask the person who gave you the assignment what they intended by "count of ALL words". You give valid reasons for the different interpretations but there's no obvious answer.

Comment: Yeah, probably I should, will have to wait a few days though until he is back. Thanks John for information btw.